# Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-compat' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am using an internal library. Because of the library my android gradle build is failing with below issues.

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-compat' that satisfies the version constraints: 

Dependency path 'Project:library:unspecified' --> 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0'
   Constraint path 'Project:library:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:{strictly 25.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 25.0.0
   Dependency path 'Project:library:unspecified' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'Project:library:unspecified' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'Project:library:unspecified' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'Project:library:unspecified' --> 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' --> 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
```

Earlier it was using the support library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Now it is moved to androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

build.gradle file of the library is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.1"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField "int", "DB_VERSION", "10"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compileOnly 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compileOnly 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    compileOnly 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Seems like firebase-jobdispatcher is deprecated and will not receive any updates for it's dependency. Check out their migration guide: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/README.md

Comment: `firebase-jobdispatcher` is deprecated. Try to migrate it to `WorkManager`. Check it: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb

Comment: It is time to migrate to [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb)

Comment: check with this migrate androidx https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings